# How to stop WSH execution while working with node.

Tags: node.js, wsh

I am running forllowing test.js file using

```
>node test.js
```

test.js is simple code

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile('2.rtf', function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(data.toString());
});
console.log("Program Ended");
```

It shows error

[image: WSH error]

so naturally I remove the extension and ran following command which worked fine.

```
node test
```

I am running windows 7 32 bit. How to stop WSH while using node commnad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have a file named `node.js` in the same directory and due to the way Windows resolves commands, it's trying to execute the file `node.js` (using the default handler for that file type, which is typically JScript) instead of `node` the node.js executable. Rename the `node.js` file to something else and it should work.

Comment: I am sorry but what you are trying say confusing me. Do you mean to say I need to change the test.js file (as in my example) or I have somewhere in my installation directory node.js file that I need to modify)

Comment: The screenshot of the error you posted shows you have a `node.js` file on your Desktop. Try renaming *that* file and try executing `node test.js` again.

Comment: Oh. I confused my self. Thanks.